# Pythonic way to perform a large case/switch

Tags: python

I'm pretty sure this is a really fundamental concept in Python, I'd love it if someone could help me understand how to do the following in a pythonic/clean way.  I'm really new to coding so I will just show an example.  I think it will be obvious what I am trying to do.

```
for textLine in textLines:
   foo = re.match('[1-100]', thing)
   if foo:
     list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Bar").fetch(100)
     if thing == '1':
       item = list[0]
     elif thing == '2':
       item = list[1]
     elif thing == '3':
       item = list[2]
     .
     .
     .
     elif thing == '100':
       item = list[99]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another Pythonic thing to do is avoid using variable names that hide built-ins.  In this case, the `list` variable is hiding the built-in `list` type. Use a more descriptive name (`bars`?) or something like `lst` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just do this

```
item = list[int(thing) - 1]
```

In more complex cases, you should use a dictionary mapping inputs to outputs.

Comment: +1 for suggesting dictionary mappings as an alternative to switch statements

Answer (score 7):

For the specific code you're showing, the pythonic thing would be to replace the entire if-ladder with:

```
item = list[int(thing)-1]
```

Of course, it's possible that your real code doesn't lend itself to collapsing like this.

Comment: That's not just Pythonic, it's good practice in any language.

Comment: Oh yeah...that seems rather obvious in retrospect.  Thanks!

Comment: Daily WTF submission averted!